# How to get the values that a user submits through an html form on Google Chrome with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing my first chrome extension which has the following functionality. When a user right clicks an image and selects the appropriate field in the context menu, a popup window containing a form is created. The following function is called from the context menu.

```
   function new_window(){chrome.windows.create({
                                   url: "reddit.html",
                                   type: "popup",
                                   focused: true,
                                   width: 200,
                                   height:140})
```

The form which is contained inside "reddit.html" is the following:

```
     <form id="post_on_forum" method="get">
         <input type="text" name="title" placeholder ="title"><br>
         <input type ="text" name="Category"placeholder ="Category" ></br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">                   
     </form>
```

My question is:  How can I get with Javascript the variables that the user enters everytime he submits something ? I cannot use inline javascript since chrome prohibits that. I have created a `submit.js` which is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Submit').on('click',(function() {
       foo($('#post_on_forum').val());
    }));

    console.log("triggered");
});
```

but it doesn't work. I have included on the manifest file all the appropriate files of course.

Comment: do you get an error in the console?

Comment: none I don't get anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/qt3ZB/

jQuery has special method `serialize` to get all values from form.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , my problem is that it seems that Chrome doesn't "register" the click of the submit button. When i do it on my server instead of the extension it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Below code will serialize form inputs in this format (controlName1=controlValue1&controlName2=controlValue2)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Submit').on('click',(function() {
    var formElements = $('#post_on_forum').serialize();       
    //then use this formElements wherever you like
 });
});
```